# Can Windows 10 OS be used on a hard drive with a MacBook

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

My computer knowledge is casual/everyday person. I could not understand a lot of the similar questions in this site. So, I hope there is someone who could help me.

In search of a way to play Windows video games on a new computer, I was wondering if I could use an external hard drive I had laying around and my 2017 MacBook Air to play those games. I also have a laptop from about 2010 with Windows 10 if that helps my chances of executing this.

I shall share information that might be relevant, I'm not  sure.

External Hard Drive Specs: Seagate STDR1000300 or Model SRD00F1 (These are links I could find about it:
https://www.cnet.com/products/seagate-backup-plus-stdr1000300-hard-drive-1-tb-usb-3-0/ ,
https://www.barcodelookup.com/763649053058 ,
https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/bup-slim-rose-goldDS1803-7-1705-APAC-en_AU.pdf )

Laptop I was thinking of playing games on: MacBook Air Model A1466

I also have a laptop with Windows 10 if obtaining an OS is of concern.

I wasn't sure how to write about this but I would love to hear if anything is possible. I might have misunderstood the possibilities of these hardware. I just really want to be able to play Valorant but my old Windows computer sucks and I only have these two items which I believe there might be a way to make it so I could play video games. I am more than willing to be helped, to help you help me, and to learn of topics relevant to help me, so long as it is safe.

Comment: Keywords: _Bootcamp_ and _Windows To Go_. I don't know if these two work together, but try googling these terms.

Comment: Bootcamp would be your best bet for playing the games directly on the Mac. Another option would be GeForce Now. The free version will allow you to stream games on your Mac that you own. It actually works really good. However, I don't think a MacBook Air would do very good for games. I tired playing some games on my MacBook Pro and it was terrible. I'd say the Windows 10 laptop might be your better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help I've been receiving. I found that the most relevant answer was trying GeForce Now. I do not think I can afford a license, I was hoping I could find a way to use the items I had to do something. I shall hope I can get a PC in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Windows to Go is not supported and I do not think it is current. I don't suggest Windows to Go. Dual Boot appears to cause more issues than most methods. Great until one of the systems refuses to boot.

Try instead Virtualization:  VMware Fusion or Parallels. Your old laptop license likely cannot be used so you will need to buy a license in any event.

I have virtualized two Linux Systems on my Windows 10 box and (a) they work great and (b) updates on the host and on the guests do not conflict in any way. Firmware and BIOS updates on the host just cause a restart and I close down guests before doing this.

This is a good way to go, especially with a good fast SSD main drive.

Virtualization is much easier to implement than dual boot in most cases.

If you want a strong Windows gaming platform, you might find it better and easier to have a separate Windows machine that will run all your games.

Comment: Virtualisation is not much good for gaming

Comment: Windows To Go isn't _officially_ supported, but it still works (backwards compatibility I guess). See [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1605207/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-100-of-a-software-that-is-not-yet-installed#comment2447165_1605213).

Comment: it might be better to have a separate Windows gaming machine. I added that possibility to my answer.